# Nodejs express JWT how to strore and send token from web/phone client (jsonwebtoken)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm using NodeJs with Express app to develop webs for browsers and mobile phones. I'm using JWT because it seems to be the standard and I read that sessions doesn't work well in phones (without browser). I have this code in the backend configured using "jsonwebtoken":

```
'use strict';

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const privateKEY  = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'private.key'), 'utf8');
const publicKEY  = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'public.key'), 'utf8');

module.exports = {

    sign: (payload) => {
        var signOptions = {
            expiresIn: process.env.TOKEN_EXPIRE_TIME,
            algorithm: "RS256"
        };
        return jwt.sign(payload, privateKEY, signOptions);
    },

    verify: (token) => {
        var verifyOptions = {
            expiresIn: process.env.TOKEN_EXPIRE_TIME,
            algorithm: ["RS256"]
        };
        try {
            return jwt.verify(token, publicKEY, verifyOptions);
        } catch (err) {
            return false;
        }
    },

    decode: (token) => {
        return jwt.decode(token, {
            complete: true
        });
    }

};
```

But I don't know which is the way to implement the front end side. I need to know how to store the token for both devices (localStorage? sessionStorage? cookies? others?) and what could be a good way to make the links (href tag in html) sending the token from that storage method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of storage for the JWT token at the front-end is totally dependent on your applications requirement and how do you want to handle user's login/logout session.

> See this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-authentication-easier-with-json-web-token-cc15df3f2228) on JWT uses, give a clap if you like

If you're not clear about this then you can usr localStorage as the data stored in it stays event after the browser is closed - if it doesn't bother your requirement.

For sending token from link - there is two things you can do -

1. Create the link dynamically and add the token as query parameter to your link
2. Or you can create onClick event which fetches the token from storage and fires a request to your server

I hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect, I was doing something similar as you say, but I didn't know if it was a good idea or if there is something better best practices. Probably the 2º method will be better for me to hide the url token on browser. nice article. Lots of thanks